# Streaming updates with RTK-Query mutation and updating cache

Tags: redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I'm using sockets to allow users to send messages in real-time. I read the RTK-Query documentation and saw an example for a query, where I would be fetching data, as opposed to mutating/sending data.

Is there any difference in implementation between fetching and posting using streaming/sockets?  I tried to understand how it works with query, and apply that to mutation, but it didn't exactly work.

I am struggling to get this to work, so any help would be appreciated.